# Efficient way to extract column values from sorted data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a data frame (sorted by column1) df:

```
column1   column2
1           'Yes'
1           'No'
2           'Yes'
3           'Yes'
3           'Yes'
3           'Yes'
```

For every value in column 1, I want to know its possible values in column2, and store these key-value pair in a structure.

For example, given the above df, I want a structure like

```
{1: ['yes','No']; 2: ['Yes'], 3:['Yes']}
```

I did something like

```
for key in df[column1].unique.tolist():
   values = df.loc[df[column1] == key]][column2].unique().tolist()
   dict.add((key, values))
```

However, as my original df is really big, this method takes too long.
As the df is sorted by column1, I wonder if there is a more efficient method to achieve this.

Thank you!

Comment: Kindly provide dataframes and expected output to understand your question easily

Comment: hi sorry, I just added some examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove redundant data with `duplicates`, then `groupby` by one column, take unique values, and save to dict:

```
final_dict = df.drop_duplicates().groupby('column1')['column2'].unique().to_dict()
```

Comment: Why is `drop_duplicates` needed?

Comment: not needed, but, in theory, performing the `groupby` only over the pertinent data should improve performance. You could make a case of the duplicates hurting performance though :)

Comment: you think so?  I'm not convinced.  I'll test it out.  anyway, my golfed answer `{**df.groupby('column1')['column2'].unique()}`

Comment: as expected from you, a beautiful answer :)

Comment: You're right!  With a large enough dataframe, `drop_duplicates` makes a difference

Comment: thank you for running the numbers, would be interesting to compute the cutoff were as the dups are meaningful

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the df.to_dict() method.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

You should be able to get something like what you want.  The example on the documentation site is as such:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2],
...                    'col2': [0.5, 0.75]},
...                   index=['row1', 'row2'])
>>> df
      col1  col2
row1     1  0.50
row2     2  0.75
df.to_dict()
{'col1': {'row1': 1, 'row2': 2}, 'col2': {'row1': 0.5, 'row2': 0.75}}
```

Looks like you updated since I posted, check this out with the 'list' arguement.

‘list’ : dict like {column -> [values]}

Answer (score 1):

First drop duplicates then apply to_dict()

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['col1','col2'],inplace=True)
df.to_dict()
```

Comment: No problem @NicoleYan